# Confusion between higher address and lower address

Tags: stack, mips, memory-address

I am very new to **Assembly language**. I was reading about **MIPS** architecture and I am stuck with a concept.

[image]
In the image above,shouldn't the **highest address be the last item of the stack** and the **lowest address at the top**? As the **address are generated in ascending order**.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The top of the stack is the position of the last element that was pushed on**. Looking at that picture, the 'top' of the stack is towards the bottom, which has a lower address. The addresses are generated in **decending**, not ascending order.

It is called the **top** as a stack is a LIFO (Last In First Out) structure - the last object added is the first one removed, and is therefore 'on top'.